# What are these black spots in Plastic lids

Tags: plastics

I have been using borosil lunch box from few months, [Borosil lunch box](http://www.myborosil.com/product/universal-klip-n-store-lunch-box-set-of-4)

After few days of using it there are few black spots started generating at the plastic lid, I tried removing them using dishwashing soap and even trying to remove it by rubbing hard but nothing happened.
Could anybody tell me what is this deposit and how could I get rid of this.
[image: Black spots in rubber rim]

Comment: Did you microwave that? It might be a fungus as the current answer suggests, but I wonder if it is imperfections/contamination in the plastic that reacted badly to being microwaved. Also, have you tried a diluted bleach cleaning?

Answer (score 3):

It may be fungus. If so, soaking it in vinegar for about 15 minutes and then washing it as regular should do. The discoloration may not disappear completely, though.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't worked

Answer (score 0):

This is mildew, a form of mold. The black stains it produces are practically impossible to remove from plastic objects.

Answer (score 0):

Use ammonia first then scrub with a brush.
Then try baking soda, scrub with a brush.
Lastly soak in bleach rinse with water while scrubbing with a brush.